# Deploy Qt 5 QML application to a real Android device

Tags: android, deployment, qml, qt5

There are many tutorials how to build an application with Qt for Android.
So I do it in these steps:

1. Installed Android SDK, NDK, JDK and Apache Ant
2. Installed Qt 5.2 for Android
3. Created simple QML application.
4. Configured virtual device from AVD Manager
5. I tried to run it and it bringed up Emulator window with my app. OK, it is going as expected.
6. Now I want to run it on real device. I have Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 10.1 P5100 so I enabled USB debug and connected it to PC.

But when I run the application, in "Select Android device" window I see only emulator, not real device.

So how can I run the application on real device?

Comment: Seems either smth's wrong with your OS (if it is Windows, you will need some Google USB driver, as I recall), or with the debug mode on the device.

Comment: Yes, I have Windows 7. I installed Samsung USB driver for Android. Debug mode on the tabled is on. Nothing changed.

Comment: Ok, in your place, I'd try the SDK tools, bypassing Creator -- `adb` or whatever enumerates the devices -- as soon as it works, you can even build and deploy Qt/QML programs from command line (if you set up the env. properly -- or I could share some scripts...). May be something is actually wrong with Windows security, and that's the reason -- if you have an Ubuntu 12/13 machine around, you could try that.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to follow the documentation
http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/qtcreator-2.8/creator-deploying-android.html

Using Ministro to manage having apk to deploy on real device is especialy a good point.

Hope it helps.

Comment: The link seems to be broken. Is this the same content? http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-deploying-android.html