# Qt5 - QML : How to deploy an application on an Android device

Tags: android, c++, qt, qml, qt5

I am using `Ubuntu 19.04` as OS, and I developed a small application using `Qt5` and `QML`.

I have been researching a way to transfer what I built so far into my `Android` phone `Note10` but also on additional `Android` devices a little bit older.

I found really a lot of tutorials on line (YouTube) but every tutorial has a different way to do that. I have never done it before and am looking for a super basic standard procedure.

I went on the [official documentation](https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qtcreator-2.8/creator-deploying-android.html) but the link goes nowhere.

How can I easily and using a step-by-step procedure deploy a basic application on my `Android` given the `OS` I am using and the fact that I programmed it in `Qt5` and `QML`?

**Things to note:** In my application I implemented the `smtp` library that is possible to find [here]

(https://github.com/bluetiger9/SmtpClient-for-Qt) and wanted to understand if there are any other things I should do since I used that external package.

I simply copied and pasted the `.h` and `.cpp` files inside my `Sources` and `Headers` folder together with the other files of the application.

Also I found [this very old post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20716012/deploy-qt-5-qml-application-to-a-real-android-device) and was wondering

if the procedure is still the same or if there is an additional step-by-step to follow.

Thank you very much for pointing in the right direction on this matter

Comment: Habe you tried https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/deployment-android.html ?

Comment: See https://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-deploying-android.html